# External pointer is not valid shiny

Tags: r, sql-server, shiny, shiny-server

I have this simple app. User write ID of station and get production data from that ID station.

```
library(shiny)
library(DBI)
library(odbc)

ui = fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Tablet operation dashboard"),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(textInput("ID", "ID:", value = "")),
    mainPanel(tableOutput("tbl"))))

server = function(input, output, session) {

  output[["tbl"]] = renderTable({
    conn = dbConnect(odbc::odbc(),
                      Driver = "SQL Server",
                      Server = "server",
                      Database = "db",
                      UID = "Bluefab",
                      PWD = "pwd",
                      Port = )
    
    on.exit(dbDisconnect(conn), add = TRUE)
    query <- "sample query"
    dbGetQuery(conn, query)
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

This works well, but I would like to add another connection and I would like make the code more readable, so I tried this

```
library(shiny)
library(DBI)
library(odbc)

ui = fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Tablet operation dashboard"),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(textInput("ID", "ID:", value = "")),
    mainPanel(tableOutput("tbl"))))

server = function(input, output, session) {

  conn_duration =  dbConnect(odbc::odbc(),
                      Driver = "SQL Server",
                      Server = "server",
                      Database = "db",
                      UID = "Bluefab",
                      PWD = "pwd",
                      Port = )

  output[["tbl"]] = renderTable({
    conn = conn_duration
    on.exit(dbDisconnect(conn), add = TRUE)
    query <- "sample query"
    dbGetQuery(conn, query)
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

But I got this error `External pointer is not valid`

I even tried this

```
conn_duration = reactiveVal(dbConnect(odbc::odbc(),
                          Driver = "SQL Server",
                          Server = "server",
                          Database = "db",
                          UID = "Bluefab",
                          PWD = "pwd",
                          Port = ))
```

and then

```
conn = conn_duration()
```

But it did not work.

Comment: It is possible that your connect isn't created. Usually the error External pointer is invalid is because of problems either in connection or if the table you're trying to read/write is not available. 
Additionally, you can also check if the user has got enough rights to access the table. As the code is not reproducible so I am not trying to reproduce the error.